# Segmentation fault when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with do-release-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

[image: segfault on second run of do-release-upgrade]

I get a segmentation fault when I try to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the command line according to the user manual. When I use Software Updater, it just stops and disappears.

The command that actually fails is:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

I have run Ubuntu on an Oracle VM machine for a long time and it was very stable.

Any idea how to solve this without reinstalling from scratch?

Here is the screenshot of `sudo do-release-upgrade` (without the `-d` flag):

[image: sudo do-release-upgrade]

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1280019/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo do-release-upgrade` (without "-d")

Comment: I edited it, as guided. The failure still exists.

Comment: That screenshot seems incomplete. When possible please copy/paste text (like terminal output) instead of screenshots.

Comment: I can't get a log file because I have a problem with the virtual machine ubuntu is running on. I added a screen shot that includes all lines.

Comment: Okay, no segmentation fault there. Now show us an output *with* the segmentation fault. We're not asking for a logfile. You could just make the window taller and scroll up a bit. Or use the VM's copy/paste function.

Comment: True. I rerun the "sudo do-release-upgrade" twice in a row. first time ended with "aborting". 2nd time with segmentation fault. A picture was added.

Comment: The most common causes for what you are showing us are 1) Non-Ubuntu packages or wrong-version packages (uninstall them), 2) Wrong version of Python3 on the system (return to the version installed with Ubuntu), 3) Network connectivity problem, 4) Corrupted package manager (reinstall apt and ubuntu-release-upgrader-core).